# Java compiler error: cannot access: class file for ... not found

Tags: java, compiler-errors, java-platform-module-system

I am getting a compile error and cannot find anything that is wrong.
Also in Eclipse the same code compiles fine.
I have the slight feeling that I have found a bug in the Java compiler.
I am using maven and Java 17:

```
Apache Maven 3.8.6 (84538c9988a25aec085021c365c560670ad80f63)
Maven home: D:\projects\mmm\software\maven
Java version: 17.0.5, vendor: Eclipse Adoptium, runtime: D:\projects\mmm\software\java
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Also the error is reproducible on CI build on github:
https://github.com/m-m-m/entity/actions/runs/3587505429/jobs/6037927761

```
Error:  Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.9.0:compile (default-compile) on project mmm-entity-db: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
Error:  /home/runner/work/entity/entity/db/src/main/java/io/github/mmm/entity/bean/db/statement/AliasMap.java:[23,7] error: cannot access CharScannerParser
Error:    class file for io.github.mmm.scanner.CharScannerParser not found
Error:  /home/runner/work/entity/entity/db/src/main/java/io/github/mmm/entity/bean/db/statement/AliasMap.java:[122,2] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:  /home/runner/work/entity/entity/db/src/main/java/io/github/mmm/entity/bean/db/statement/AliasMap.java:[126,34] error: cannot access CharStreamScanner
Error:    class file for io.github.mmm.scanner.CharStreamScanner not found
```

This is the link to the source-code:
https://github.com/m-m-m/entity/blob/20458a1ff8e154abfe6e2c28e6b1322a313fa1b3/db/src/main/java/io/github/mmm/entity/bean/db/statement/AliasMap.java#L23
The referenced class that is claimed not to be found is here:
https://github.com/m-m-m/scanner/blob/4a7494535a1c5e91c50e332653a7deb9f2a5d8c7/core/src/main/java/io/github/mmm/scanner/CharStreamScanner.java

I have created an issue in my project showing the links for all `requite transitive` statements along the dependency path from the source module to the target one so it is obviously having a dependency and the entire package is exported:
https://github.com/m-m-m/entity/issues/1

What could I be missing here?

p.s.: If Java became that complex is there any compiler option to get more verbose output to trace down errors? I am developing Java for 20 years now and would consider myself as an expert but with the complexity of the JPMS it really can get tricky to find what is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem: maven-compiler-plugin version 3.9.0 is broken and downgrading to 3.8.1 fixes the problem.
https://github.com/m-m-m/entity/commit/93660bf607de98d3bff86b9757ea13887133f3cd
Proof via green CI build:
https://github.com/m-m-m/entity/actions/runs/3587730371

Found the actual bug issue as well: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-481